# How to Check In into the Facebook.?

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Facebook app, so I wanted to make Check In throgh the Facebook Graph API so I had tried, but it will not working so my actual question is like how to make check in

```
            FacebookClient objClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

            Dictionary<string, double> objcoordinates = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            objcoordinates["latitude"] = 37.4163458217;
            objcoordinates["longitude"] = -122.15198690595;
            Dictionary<string,object> param = new Dictionary<string,object>();
            param["message"] = "Hello.!";
            param["place"]="110506962309835";
            param["coordinates"] = objcoordinates; // "'latitude'= '37.4163458217','longitude'= '-122.15198690595'";
            objClient.Post("me/checkins",param);
```

in above this ID is my pageId but I am not able to do this it will give me error.

so which method through I can achieve check in thank you..!!

I am using WPF C# app so accordingly suggest me.

or else anybody have explain step by step approach so that I can go ahead and take a look.

I am getting Error like this.
--> Error binding to target method

Comment: what has a comment todo with checkins ?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/ it seems you cant create a checkin..

Comment: still I didn't get it I read this doc but I cant understand this.

Comment: Jitendra... it is not possible.

Comment: What error are you geting? It should be possible and that code looks OK

Comment: it will give error like this.--> Error binding to target method.

Comment: That sounds like a problem in your own code or the SDK - it doesn't look like any of the error messages that come back from the API itself

Comment: ok so how I comes to know whether problem is in SDK or my code because every thing is working fine on this SDK and even my code can you more specify.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                Dictionary<string, string> objcoordinates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                objcoordinates["latitude"] = ViewModelLocator.ShareOptionsStatic._eventInfoModel.latitude == 0.0 ? "34.04503" : System.Convert.ToString(ViewModelLocator.ShareOptionsStatic._eventInfoModel.latitude);
                objcoordinates["longitude"] = ViewModelLocator.ShareOptionsStatic._eventInfoModel.longitude == 0.0 ? "-118.265633" : System.Convert.ToString(ViewModelLocator.ShareOptionsStatic._eventInfoModel.longitude);
                Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                param["message"] = "Hello.Messages.!"
                param["place"] = "49127904491";
                param["coordinates"] = objcoordinates; // "'latitude'= '37.4163458217','longitude'= '-122.15198690595'";
                objClient.PostAsync("me/checkins", param);
```